# Prove that if $a \equiv b \pmod{8}$, then $2a \equiv 2b \pmod{16}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

My professor recently assigned us a homework question but he did not cover any similar questions to it, so I do not know how to approach the problem at all.

The question is: 
Use the definition of congruence to prove that if $a \equiv b \pmod{8}$, then $2a \equiv 2b \pmod{16}$.

If any tips could be provided as to how to begin the problem,
thanks!

Comment: You yourself specified that this is your **Homework Question**, this may lead to downvotes. BTW Salute to your honesty.

Comment: Hint. Start with what the definition of congruence says about $a$, $b$ and $8$. I think that hint doesn't count as doing your homework for you.

Comment: Sorry, I was not trying to receive the full solution I just wanted some hints as to how to start the problem :(

Comment: I would say it's encouraged to say that this is homework, the community here don't like to do someones homework but like helping people do their homework

Comment: Tip is: definition is $a\equiv b \mod n$ means $a-b = 8k$ for some integer k.  SO you need to prove if $a-b = 8k$ for some $k$, that $2a-2b = 16m$ for some m$.  Which... isn't hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a \equiv b \pmod 8 \iff a - b = 8k$ for some integer $k$, $\iff 2a - 2b = 16k$ $\iff 2a \equiv 2b \pmod{16}$.

Answer (score 1):

### HINT:

$a \equiv b \pmod 8$ is equivalent to $\exists k \in \Bbb Z: a-b=8k$

$2a \equiv 2b \pmod {16}$ is equivalent to $\exists k \in \Bbb Z: 2a-2b=16k$

Comment: That's a complete solution man and you've written ##HINT ?

Comment: @JaideepKhare I'm just restating definitions.

Comment: To be fair the problem is pretty simple so a hint is basically equivalent to a solution

Comment: That's not a complete solution.  One still needs to prove $\exists k \in \mathbb Z:a-b = 8k\implies \exists k' \in \mathbb Z: 2a-2b = 16k'$.  I'd call it a bit more than a hint but it isn't a solution.  Frankly, I prefer to think of it as a dope slap.  It says "use the definition" so.... that *IS* the definition, right?

Answer (score 0):

Tip:  When something says " Use the definition of congruence" then ... use the definition of congruence.

Def: $a \equiv b \mod n \iff n|(a-b) \iff \exists k\in \mathbb Z; kn = a- b$

Can you prove $8|a-b \implies 16| 2a-2b$ or that if $\exists k; 8k = a-b \implies \exists k'; 16k' = 2a - 2b$?

Answer (score 0):

The definition of congruence says that $x \equiv y \pmod k$ if $k$ divides $x-y$.

Suppose $8$ divides $a-b$.  Then $a-b = 8 n$ for some integer $n$.  Clearly $2(a-b) = 16 n$, and so $16$ divides $2a - 2b$.  Hence, $2a \equiv 2b \pmod {16}$.